# How can I copy the whole html page with external css & images

Tags: javascript, html

I'am trying to copy a whole html page, but the css and images & javascript files are external, if there were only few of them I could copy them manually, but what if there are many of them....the links in the html pages to those files refers as local, is there a way I can copy all of the files exactly as they are in the html page? is there a tool for that? cause I can't do it in the chrome console

Comment: Did you try CTRL+s ?

Answer (score 1):

You can save a website in the MHTML format (short for MIME Encapsulation of Aggregate HTML Documents) which is an HTML document along its assets like styles or images in one single document.

Some browsers do support that format (e.g. Chrome “Save complete website”), for other clients you'
ll need to install a plugin.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Comment: Just a minor correction/update: for Chrome at today (2024-01-21) in the "Save As" dialogue window the correct option to save in **m**html format is "Webpage, **Single File**", while "Webpage, _Complete_" will save in plain html, loosing stylesheets & C. It is specified between parentheses in the dialogue dropdown list, but since "html" and "mhtml" are easily confused, better specify